# group of gwt listbox when one is selected others should un selected

Tags: gwt

I want to create a custom component which can have N number of ListBoxes and when one List box is selected then others should be un selected. is there way to do it.. can any one suggest me.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this.

One way to do this is and **internal event bus**-

1) Create an event bus for the custom widget.

2) Create a custom selected event

3) Each listbox that gets created should register a handler with this event bus for the custom selected event.

4) If a list gets selected/ focused on (whenever you want others to be deselected), it will fire the custom selected event on the event bus with its Id.

5) The other list boxes will receive this event, check if it came from them, if not, will deselect/ set selection null

Another way, rather than have the event bus control it, is to create a custom function that gets called on selection, this function will have to go through all the lists and deselect them.

Comment: Hi Jai, thanks for reply, do you any sample code that will help me do it.

Comment: I have code that I cant share unfortunately. But it shouldn't be too difficult. Try solution 2 if you are not comfortable with event buses. Create a custom widget with an array of ListBoxes, each with a custom debug id. To each, add a selection handler, which calls a function that goes through all other lists and deselects them. Try creating as much as u can, you can ask specific questions if you get stuck.

Comment: Am very new to GWT, if you sample code for this, please provide me, mean while i will try.

Answer (score 0):

Jai gave you some good ideas, but here is my code for similar functionality (not N ListBoxes, but you should be able to extend/generalize it):

```
@UiHandler({ "listBox1", "listBox2" })
public void onFocus(FocusEvent e) {
  // If one ListBox has an item selected, and the user click's the other, unselect previous (mutually exclusive).
  if (listBox1.getSelectedIndex() > -1 || listBox2.getSelectedIndex() > -1) {
    if (listBox1.getSelectedIndex() > -1 && e.getRelativeElement() == listBox2.getElement()) {
      listBox1.setSelectedIndex(-1);
    }
    else if (listBox2.getSelectedIndex() > -1 && e.getRelativeElement() == listBox1.getElement()) {
      listBox2.setSelectedIndex(-1);
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, I used the UiHandler syntax, and I performed the "is selected" check during the onFocus event. In English:

1. If any ListBox has an item selected (if no ListBox has an item selected, no sense in checking all of them).
2. If ListBox 1 has an item selected, and the (focus) event came from any other ListBox:

   - Yes - deselect ListBox 1 item
   - No - repeat step 2 for ListBox 2 ... N